# How can https://www.whatismyip.com/ see my LAN IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, privacy

The website is showing my correct internal LAN IP address.

https://www.whatismyip.com/

[image]

It does not work in Safari.

[image]

I do not suspect this is an XKCD #628 attack. How is this website implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of WebRTC feature.WebRTC feature will leak your IP address even if you are behind a proxy server or using a VPN service.

Comment: This sounds very interesting and goes against many of the Internets common knowledge bases, would be nice for a more detailed answer.